# Angular: How to send a string to an injection service?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, dependencies, code-injection

i created generic service to crud task, the service use the HttpClient by DI (Dependency Injection), but i need to inform another value in the constructor of the service, how to make this?

because when I define that in the constructor of my class that will consume the CRUD service using DI, there is no way to pass the parameter to the constructor

below is the service

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { CrudInterface } from "@app/core/crud.interface";
import { environment } from "@env/environment";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class CRUD<T> implements CrudInterface<T>{
    
    endpoint: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, routeDir: string){
        this.endpoint = `${environment.endpoint}/${routeDir}`;
    }
    
    getAll(): Observable<T[]> {
        return this.http.get<T[]>(`${this.endpoint}`);
    }

    get(id: number): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.get<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
    }

    create(object: T): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.post<T>(`${this.endpoint}`, object);
    }

    update(object: T): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.put<T>(`${this.endpoint}`, object);
    }

    delete(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
    }

}
```

```js
import { Usuario } from "@app/usuarios/model/usuario";
import { CRUD } from "@app/core/crud.service";

class TestCrudServide {

    constructor(
        /**
         * How to inform the parameter here?
         * in this case the endpoint (2nd parameter of the CRUD service)
         */
        private crudService: CRUD<Usuario>
    ){ }

    getAll(){
        this.crudService.getAll();
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

utilizing a solution proposed by Sannon Aragão (thanks) of the concept of factories, i created the service provider for create the instance dynamically

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#factory-providers

```js
export class crudServiceProvider {

    static getProvider(routeDir: string) {
        return {
            provide: CRUD,
            deps: [HttpClient],
            useFactory: (dep) => {
                return new CRUD(dep, routeDir);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in my component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-revenda',
  templateUrl: './revenda.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./revenda.component.css'],
  providers:[ crudServiceProvider.getProvider('/api/revenda') ]
})
export class RevendaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
      private crudService: CRUD<Revenda>
    ) { }
    
    ngOnInit() {
      // now it's work with the correct path and type!
      this.crudService.get(1).subscribe(item => console.log(item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filipe, from the module with you want to provide your service:

```
{
provide: 'userService1',
deps: [ HttpClient ],
useFactory: (dep1 ) => {
    return new UserService( dep1, 'test');
  }
}
```

In the component where you will use the service:

```
constructor( @Inject('userService1') private userService: UserService ) { }
```

In the CRUD API you get the parameter as string:

```
constructor( private http: HttpClient, private s: string) {
  console.log(s); // will print 'test'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do this with how dependency injection works. What you can do is create a base CRUD class

```
export class CRUD<T> implements CrudInterface<T>{

    endpoint: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, routeDir: string){
        this.endpoint = `${environment.endpoint}/${routeDir}`;
    }

    getAll(): Observable<T[]> {
        return this.http.get<T[]>(`${this.endpoint}`);
    }

    get(id: number): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.get<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
    }

    create(object: T): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.post<T>(`${this.endpoint}`, object);
    }

    update(object: T): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.put<T>(`${this.endpoint}`, object);
    }

    delete(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
    }

}
```

Then make an Injectable service that extends the CRUD class

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService extends CRUD<Usario> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient){
        super(http, 'users');
    }
}
```

`UserService` is the class that you provide in AppModule and inject into your component. You can see that super is being used to pass in the `routeDir` parameter. Here is a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reusable-crud-service-llai?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demoing this.

Comment: I understood, so what I intended would not work ... I would like to create a generic service for do not have to create other services just to implement the base crud service, thus avoiding the creation of several files with the same functionalities, but thanks for your solution I'll use it

Comment: @FilipeMansano I would say it's good to have these "middle layer" classes. Say it was possible to do something like `constructor(private crudService('user'): CRUD<Usario>){}`. If you were to add this to multiple components, each component would have to specify the string passed in. With the middle layer class, you simply import and inject.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot implement anything inside of the constructor. you have to inject httpservice object(crudservice) and you have to pass a parameter to functions.

To implement the second one you have to do something like this

`this.crudService.get(10);`