# How to inject custom string into service constructor in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 3 components which do almost the same things and I want to extract their logic into a shared service. But it requires a string "type" which defines the url that will be used later on.
My idea was to pass the type string as a constructor parameter in my component's providers:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HelperService,
      useFactory: (type: string, termService: TermService) =>
        new HelperService(type, termService),
      deps: ['userTerms', HelperService],
    },
  ],
})
```

But that leads to an error:

> ERROR
> Error: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[userTerms -> userTerms -> userTerms]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for userTerms!

Here is an example project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gyfpvy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhelper.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fterm.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Is there a simple way to achieve this and pass a string?

Comment: Have you looked at the following example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064920/angular-how-to-send-a-string-to-an-injection-service

Comment: @monstertjie_za thank you, I did not found this thread yet. Will look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the option mentioned in the comments that you just include the string in the factory you can also do this using an [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken).
You define an InjectionToken for the string value and inject it in the constructor of the service.
For example:

```
export const HELPER_TYPE = new InjectionToken<string>('Helper service type');

@Injectable()
export class HelperService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(HELPER_TYPE) private readonly type: string,
    private readonly termService: TermService
  ) {}
}
```

This the simplifies the providers in the component because you don´t need to use a factory.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  providers: [
    TermService,
    { provide: HELPER_TYPE, useValue: 'userTerms' },
    HelperService
  ],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(helper: HelperService) {}
}
```

Here is also a [link to a fork of your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ewctns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhelper.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) implementing this solution.

Comment: This is absolutely great and reduces the boilerplate. Thanks!